# Prove that the sum of all the nil right ideals of $R$ is a 2-sided ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Prove that the sum of all the nil right ideals of $R$ is a nil 2-sided ideal.

I need help showing that that the sum of all nil right ideals is is a nil ideal. I've shown it is an ideal already:

$proof:$

First note that if $I$ is a right nil ideal of $R$ and $r \in R$ then $rI$ is also a right nil ideal. This is because of $(xr)^n=0$ then $(rx)^{n+1}=0$

Let $S$ be the sum of all nil right ideals of R and let $y \in S$.

Then $y = y_1 + y_2 + ... +y_k$ where $y_i \in I_i$ where $I_i$ is a right ideal of $R$.

Then $ry = r(y_1 + y_2 + ... +y_k)$ and $ry_i \in rI_i$.

And $S$ is obviously a right ideal.

Thus $S$ is an ideal of $R$. Showing that it is nil is proving to be a little harder, maybe I'll need a generalized binomial formula? Can somebody help walk me through this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note: This answer only shows that the sum of nil ideals is nil in a commutative ring.**

As pointed out by rschwieb, that question is open for non-commutative rings. I'll leave this here in case anyone finds the argument helpful in proving the commutative case.

---

We can avoid having to use the multinomial theorem, which would be messy. Elements $s\in S$ are of the form $s=x_1+\cdots+x_n$ for some $n\geq1$ and $x_i\in I_i$, where $I_i$ is a nil ideal. Then we can use induction on $n$ to show that each $s$ is nilpotent.

The result is obvious for $n=1$. If we have $s=x_1+\cdots+x_n$, then $r=x_1+\cdots+x_{n-1}$ is nilpotent by the inductive hypothesis, say $r^a=0$ for some $a\geq1$. We know that $x_n^b=0$ for some $b\geq1$. Then by the usual binomial theorem we have $$s^{a+b}=(r+x_n)^{a+b}=\sum_{k=0}^{a+b}\binom{a+b}{k}r^{a+b-k}x_n^k$$ From this, we can see in the sum that as soon as we have fewer than $a$ lots of $r$ we will have at least $b$ lots of $x_n$, and so the sum will be $0$. Then $s^{a+b}=0$, so $s$ is nilpotent and we are done by induction.

Comment: Sorry to potentially be the bearer of bad news, but I don't think it is likely that a simple proof exists.  As I'm suggesting in my solution, I think proving the problem posed (the sum of all nil right ideals is nil) would be a resolution to the longstanding Köthe conjecture, which is still unsolved AFAIK.   I wanted to ask: did you have commutativity in mind when formulating the answer?  That would make the problem accessible to a simple proof.

Comment: Ah yes, apologies, I've assumed commutativity when writing out the sum, the terms might be a mess of $rx_n^3r^2x_n$ etc. Thanks for pointing that out. Also I think you're right, from the phrasing talking about right ideals it seems we don't necessarily have commutativity. I'll add a note to my answer, looks like Köthe has got the better of me!

Comment: No problem: this happens to everyone occasionally!

Answer (score 1):

I take it from your mention of "right ideal" in your work that you're dealing with noncommutative rings.

A proof of your question would amount to a proof of the [Köthe conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6the_conjecture) which is still unsolved.  (If the sum of all nil right ideals is guaranteed to be a nil ideal, then in particular the sum of any two nil right ideals is a nil right ideal.)

I notice that the title of your question simply says "*Prove that the sum of all the nil right ideals of  **is a 2-sided ideal***" which is true, as you demonstrated. Is it possible that your idea to prove it is additionally nil something that just slipped in later by accident?